# Unable to fetch the latest changes made to editor-style.css (wordpress)

Tags: css, wordpress

I am using twentyseventeen as my theme to create a website.

When I am using classic editor to upload the content, the window of classic editor doesn't expand more than 580px because of a css.

I changed the css blocking the max-width and cleared the cache. However, the website is still fetching the same css not allowing the updated css to execute.

Editor-style.css earlier had the following code

```
body {
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #333;
    margin: auto 20px;
    max-width: 580px;
}
```

This is the updated code where I changed the max-width to 100%.

[[What gets fetched]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UFzTj.png)

This is what still gets fetched. It shows max-width:580px.

What's the issue here?

I tried changing the code in the source css (editor-style.css.

Comment: Do you mean server cache, when you're talking about cache ? Have you tried to force your web browser to fully refresh the page ? By the way, you should not use image for code. To know why, you can consult this [post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors).

Comment: I have cleared the server cache and also forced the browser to fully refresh the page. I shared the image to show the previous code. I'll post a snippet instead. thanks.